# Javascript, determine if an href click is a call to javascript function or not

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events, onbeforeunload

I'm tying in to the `onbeforeunload` event in Javascript to disable control of the page during the unload process.  We have a bunch of users who were editing data during this time and it was wreaking havoc on the product.

There are a bunch of links that show up on the page that have `href="javascript:....."`.

Clicking these links fires the disabling code, which makes the page impossible to use.  Is there a way I can detect if the `onbeforeunload` event is navigating to a different page or just firing this Javascript?

Comment: Don't think there is. It's bad to be using `javascript:` anyway. Use `onclick` handlers, preferably with them not being inline.

Comment: e.preventDefault is probably what your'e after for the href="javascript:... stuff

Comment: @Amaan I wish I had the authority to make those changes.

Comment: @HollyStyles I can just not execute the code if I can figure out how to detect the outgoing url

Comment: event.target.href.startsWith('javascript') ? something like that?

Comment: @HollyStyles event.target is undefined in the onbeforeunload event

Comment: Yes you'll need to Google around that a bit for a cross browser way of gettin g the element reference that just fired the event.

Comment: @HollyStyles  That's what my current plan of attack is.  The best I've been able to do is get the window object, which doesn't help very much.

Comment: how about this? oooh look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8581650/window-onbeforeunload-is-it-possible-to-get-any-details-about-how-the-window-wa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't the most reliable way of checking for this but it works for my purposes:

```
$('*:focus').attr('href')
```

Answer (score 0):

Have every href link visit a piece of javascript code which does inspection on the href contents before it is executed.

```
event.target.href.startsWith('javascript')
```

If yes, submit the request, if not, do something else.