# on clicking the close button of any browser, is there any specific event related to close button, in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way to call a JavaScript "onbeforeunload" function only when the user clicks the browser close button?

Currently, it triggers the event on page refresh, page navigation and browser exit.

Comment: In answer to your question: "No."

Comment: The onbeforeunload works for me on FireFox and Chrome.

See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311341/confirmation-before-closing-of-tab-browser

Comment: The answer is Yes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8582044/2375207 but you will have to dig in the event object. (Check the window.event.srcElement)

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to know the type of window closing.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a close action for the browser in Javascript.  The closest you could get to this implementation would be Javascript's close() function.  However, you would need to rely on your user to click this button to close the window each time for this to work properly.  Generally speaking, it is not feasible.

[Here is some more information about Javascript's close() function.](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_close.asp)