# how to stop calling onbeforeunload event while page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

I am trying to update database while user closing browser/tap.I tried with onbeforeunload function and its working fine but even in page refreshing.Here is code what i tried

MyJSP :

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var refresh=false;

            $(window).keydown(function(event){
                if(event.keyCode==116)
                    {       
                    refresh=true;
                    }
                    })

            $(window).on('beforeunload', function(){ 

                if(refresh==false)
                    {
                    $.get("BrowserCloseServlet", function() {

                    });
                    }

            });

      </script>
```

MyServlet :

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        String getId = request.getParameter("getid");
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement pst = null;
        PreparedStatement pst2 = null;
        ResultSet rst = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/raptor1_5", "root", "");
            String query = "select NoOfCount from tbl_BroserCloseTable ";
            String query2 = "update tbl_BroserCloseTable set NoOfCount= ? where Sno= ?";
            // Statement st = con.createStatement();
            // st.executeUpdate("");
            pst = con.prepareStatement(query);

            rst = pst.executeQuery(query);
            if (rst.next()) {
                int count = rst.getInt(1);
                System.out.println("Actuall count is :" + count);
                count -= 1;

                pst2 = con.prepareStatement(query2);
                pst2.setInt(1, count);
                pst2.setInt(2, 1);
                pst2.executeUpdate();
                System.out.println("Updated successfully...");

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                con.close();
                rst.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
```

Its working fine(not update DB while click f5 button) but if the user click on refresh button then that servlet page called and updated DB.I want to stop calling onbeforeunload when click on refresh button in browser.

Update :

I only want  to know how make that **refresh=false;** while click on refresh button in browser.

How to do this one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [window.onbeforeunload: Is it possible to get any details about how the window was unloaded?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8581650/window-onbeforeunload-is-it-possible-to-get-any-details-about-how-the-window-wa)